# MouseEvent does not propagate when creating it "manually" with MouseEvent constructor

Tags: javascript, dom-events

If I have nested divs and click the innermost, the event propagates all the way up. If I dispatch a `MouseEvent` created "manually" it won't propagate:

However, if I "save" a `MouseEvent` which is actually dispatched when clicking with the mouse, and then dispatch this event, it will propagate.

So I think I will need to set some property on the `MouseEvent` to make it propagate. Is that possible?

The code below demonstrates the issue:

**HTML**

```
<div id='div1'>
    #div1
    <div id='div2'>
        #div2
        <div id='div3'>
            #div3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var mostRecentEvent;
function handler(e) { 
    console.log(e); 
    mostRecentEvent=e;
};

var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
for (var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].addEventListener('click', handler);
};

// Will not propagate
var homeBakedMouseEvent = new MouseEvent('click');
document.querySelector('#div3').dispatchEvent(homeBakedMouseEvent);

// Will propagate 
// But can only be run after actually clicking with mouse. 
// So run this line from console
// document.querySelector('#div3').dispatchEvent(mostRecentEvent);
```

Comment: So the answer is: `new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true})`.

Comment: @Oriol: While your approved answer for the other question did reveal the answer, the questions seem very different. I wouldn't call it a duplicate. If someone experiences that a "manually constructed" event does not bubble, like I did, he would never google for smth that would show the other question.

Comment: Having a question closed as a duplicate is nothing bad at all. As you say, thanks to your question more people will be able to find the other one. Closing as duplicate is just a way to avoid repeating the same answers everywhere.